# Wordpress merge multiple sites into one multi user site

Tags: wordpress

I have about 15 standalone instances of Wordpress. Each using a different woo theme that has been customized and some plugins.

Is there an easy way to retain all plugin and theme settings when migrating to wordpress multisite?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow [Migrating multiple blogs Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite) recommendations. But if you have different customized versions of plugins on your sites - it seems you are in trouble then...

Comment: I have been, that's where I am running into trouble. But thank you!